# How do I specify a URL pattern for a function in PHP?

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, rest

I am trying to use `PHP`, `REST` and `Angular`.

I have a `userAPI.php` file which has several functions like: `getUser($uid)`, etc.

I hava a DAO method which return the `userObject` from the database of the specified `userID`.

Now, in Java when we use JAX-RS we can specify URL pattern with annotation which looks something like:

```
@url('user/{uid}')'
@get
public void getUser(Integer uid){
   //func body
}
```

But I am not sure how to do that in PHP.

Then I googled and got to know about `.htaccess`.

I tried:

```
RewriteRule user/(.*)$ php/service/userAPI.php?uid=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

But I am not sure if it's correct.

What should I write inside `.htaccess` and `$http.get()` ?

Comment: You should probably use an MVC framework rather than pure PHP. If you do insist on doing this, just know that your `userAPI.php` should have code which runs when the file is called, rather than just functions.

Comment: So I should make seperate files instead of functions? @apokryfos

Comment: @apokryfos And could you suggest any framework?

Comment: I use Laravel, but there's some other good ones too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PHP script does not call any functions automatically. To test whether your rewrite rule is taking effect do the following:

**userAPI.php**

```
<?php
require_once "userMethods.php"

$uId = (isset($_GET["uid"]))?$_GET["uid"]:null);
if ($uId === null) {
    echo "No user id provided";
}
$user = getUser($id);
```

**userMethods.php**

```
<?php
function getUser($id) {
     //Get the user 
}
// Other functions?
```

While it is possible to declare all functions in the `userAPI.php` file before any of the code which will run, it's probably better practice to separate function declarations (and class declarations) from runnable scripts.

I do however suggest you use a proper PHP MVC framework. [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) is a pretty good one, though it does have a learning curve so if you just need to do some simple things in PHP and then never code in it again it probably isn't worth the time investment.

Comment: I think the rewrite rule is also not working:  I wrote the function code directly inside the file:

`$user_obj = getUser($_GET['uid']);
$user_arr['uname'] = $user->getUname();
echo json_encode($user_arr);`    

It echo's the JSON when I write: `http://localhost/SiteName/php/service/userAPI.php?uid=3`   

 But shows 404 with : `http://localhost/SiteName/user/3`

Comment: According to http://htaccess.mwl.be/ `http://localhost/SiteName/user/3` should get rewritten as `http://localhost/SiteName/php/service/userAPI.php?uid=3` are you sure mod_rewrite is working?

Comment: I am not sure. I saw this in a tutorial: `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule user/(.*)$ php/service/userAPI.php?uid=$1 [QSA,NC,L]`

Answer (score 0):

You Should really look at this. This will handle all of the routing for you and is pretty easy to set up. Once the routes are defined you can call your own functions.

http://www.slimframework.com/